# How to resolve Illegal number: -1.00 | ubuntu

Tags: shell-script, arithmetic

I have a scenario where I am taking difference of two numbers.

Then the calculated difference needs to be checked within a range.
If it lie within that range then display status as success, else display  failure.

**Below is my code**

```
Range = -1 to 1

var1=12.23
var2=13.23

diff=$(echo "($var1-$var2)"| bc -l)
echo $diff

if [ "$diff" -ge -1 ] && [ "$diff" -le 1 ]; then
        echo "$diff" "success"
else
   echo "Not within range -1 to 1"
   echo "Failure"
fi
```

**Error getting like below**

```
script.sh: 8: [: Illegal number: -1.00
```

Comment: The shell only does integer arithmetics and tests against integers. See e.g. [How to do integer & float calculations, in bash or other languages/frameworks?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/40786) You may want to call `bc` or some other tool to calculate the value of `($var1 - $var2) > 1` (etc.) instead and use the boolean value of that in your script.

Comment: @Kusalananda  can you write code for me which work | how to resolve this error | i have ubuntu

Comment: @Kusalananda  the calculated difference i need to check within range of -1 to 1. If the difference falls under this range i need success status as 1 or display as 0

Comment: @Kusalananda  1 = success and 0 = Fail

Comment: There is an error in line one. Only post code that you have run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to play with `awk` you can use script like:

```
var1=12.23
var2=13.23
echo |awk -v v1=$var1 -v v2=$var2 '{diff=v1-v2;if(diff >= -1 && diff <=1) print diff " success" ;else printf "%s not within range [-1,1]\nFailure\n", diff }'
```

Comment: code not working

Comment: @techvikky, now should work

Comment: code working as expected

Answer (score 1):

The shell can't compare strings that represent floating point values in arithmetic contexts.  You can however use `bc` to evaluate a boolean (integer) value that you *can* use in the shell:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

val1=12.23
val2=13.23

difference=$( bc -l <<<"$val1 - $val2" )
range_ok=$( bc -l <<<"$difference >= -1 && $difference <= 1" )

if [ "$range_ok" -ne 0 ]; then
        printf '%s success\n' "$difference"
else
        printf '%s not within range [-1,1]\n' "$difference"
        echo "Failure"
fi
```

Comment: let me check the code does it full my requirement or not

Comment: this test case fails :  if var1=12 and var2=13 result = -1 ..even if it gives equal to -1 the script should display success and vice versa

Comment: range_ok=$( bc -l <<<"$difference > -1" && "$difference < 1" && "$difference == 1" && "$difference == -1" )

Comment: @techvikky The code I posted does that correctly already. Note that I'm using `>=` and `<=`.

Comment: code is working as expected